# special characters in xml stax parser file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

```
original xml file: 
<root> <article>
<artists><artist role="A&amp;R Staff" id="1">Vance</artist><artists></article>
</root>
```

When i read the file using stax parser and writing it to the new file it creates which makes the invalid xml file because there is no &amp in the new file.

Comment: The problem is more likely to be in the writing part, can you show the corresponding code?

Comment: hi jorn i have added the writing part

Comment: Don't rely on `XmlEvent.toString()` to produce well-formed XML. Use an [XMLStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html)

Answer (score -2):

Below is working for me :

```
// This can be any InputStream
InputStream is;
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
// Set this property to handle special HTML characters like & etc.
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);
// Now use the factory to get the EventReader from the InputStream
XMLEventReader eventReader = factory.createXMLEventReader(is);
```